# Excel VBA - Copy cells based on criteria to another workbook saved in the same folder

Tags: excel, vba, copy, criteria

I'm pretty  new at this and I've gone through a ton of bundle of tutorials but I can't seem to grasp the concept of how to achieve this result in excel VBA. I'll try being as detailed as possible.

I have a folder with 3 x Excel files -

- **Script.xlsx** (Just a button that holds the script/macro)
- **WhiteCrown.xlsx** (the workbook I'd like to copy the data from)
- **PackCon.xlsx** (the workbook I'd like the data pasted into)

Concept: 
If Workbook ("WhiteCrown.xlsx") contains value in Column B5:B10000 which = Workbook ("PackCon.xlsx") Column B5:B10000 AND Workbook ("WhiteCrown.xlsx") contains a value in Column E

There are 2 cells I don't want the value of E copied - "soy-milk" "Pepsi-max"

The check is to be looped till column b 
Reaches 10000

:) thanks in advance

```
Sub ConvertData()

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
Dim Desc As Range, ExDesc As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rngLookup As Range
Dim v

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\amir.abdul\Desktop\Completed\New folder\WhiteCrown.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("BOMQ")

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\amir.abdul\Desktop\Completed\New folder\PackCon.xlsx")
With wb2.Sheets("("BOMQ")")
    Set rngLookup = .Range(.Cells(7, 2), _
                    .Cells(7, 2).End(xlDown)).Resize(, 3)
End With

With ws1
    i = 7
    Do Until .Cells(i, 2) = ""
        v = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 2).Value, rngLookup, 3, False)
        If Not IsError(v) Then .Cells(i, 4).Value = v
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With

wb2.Close False


End Sub
```

*Script updated but still not working

Comment: Please show what you've tried already.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Try coding the logic you explain and post back with issues.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and perform the operation manually to see what `VBA` Excel creates?

Comment: I'll log in from a computer to add my script as it's not letting me add it through my cell phone. I basically went through a bundle of tutorials that do similar tasks but I wasn't able to get the result I waned...please give me moment as I'm currently on the go.

Comment: I have tried the macro but it didn't work correctly validating the data being copywd

Comment: @pteranodon and @ Kyle I've added the Script

Answer (score 0):

I do not Understand what data you would like to copy. I have exhibited the logic to do so. Tested and working.

> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Private Sub btnScript_Click()
>
> Dim WhiteCrown As Workbook, PackCon As Workbook, DestWorkbook As Workbook
> Dim SheetWhiteCrown As Worksheet, SheetPack As Worksheet
> Dim RowIndex As Long
> Dim RngWhite As Range
> Dim RngWhiteCount As Long
> Dim ValBWhite, ValBPack, ValEWhite As String
>
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
> Set WhiteCrown = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Stackoverflow\WhiteCrown.xlsx")
> Set SheetWhiteCrown = WhiteCrown.Sheets("BOMQ")
> Set RngWhite = SheetWhiteCrown.Range("RngWhiteData")
>
> RngWhiteCount = SheetWhiteCrown.Range("RngWhiteData").Rows.Count + 5
>
>
> Set PackCon = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Stackoverflow\PackCon.xlsx")
> Set SheetPack = PackCon.Sheets("BOMQ")
>
> Set DestWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Stackoverflow\Script.xlsx")
>
> For RowIndex = 5 To RngWhiteCount
>      ValBWhite = SheetWhiteCrown.Cells(RowIndex, "B").Value
>      ValBPack = SheetPack.Cells(RowIndex, "B").Value
>      ValEWhite = SheetWhiteCrown.Cells(RowIndex, "E").Value
>
>     If Not ValBWhite = "" And ValBWhite = "" Then
>
>          If Not ((ValEWhite = "SoyMilk") Or (ValEWhite = "Pepsi")) Then
>
>            'Perform your copy to Destworkbook or vlookup or anything               
>          Else
>              'Do Nothing
>          End If
>
>     End If
>
> Next RowIndex
> WhiteCrown.Close
> PackCon.Close
> DestWorkbook.Close False
>
> End Sub
> ```

Never use hardocode ranges like  Range("B10:E60"). Best coding practise involved using named ranges as in the above code(example "RngWhiteData" is named range). Add error validations.

If you're satisfied please vote this answer.

Regards,

Mani